# Unable to load a Blazor webassembly application when published on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

On the development laptop using a local IIS with Visual Studio everything works fine. On the server where I published the application through Azure Devops the Blazor app fails to load with this javascript error

```
System.ArgumentException: The URI 'http://10.144.2.7/SincroADR_Api/' is not contained by the base URI 'http://10.144.2.7/SincroADR_API/'.
```

On the index.html of the Blazor Client App I have this base url

```
<base href="/SincroADR_API/" />
```

SincroADR_API is a .Net Core 3.1 Web Api project, IIS server is version 7.5 (Win 2k8 R2), IIS local is 10 (Win 10).

All the Blazor files (js, webassembly) are downloaded correctly on the browser, but I can't understand why in a local IIS it works. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The href attribute in the base tag must match the corresponding part of the URL of the request, **including the case of symbols**. If you look at the error message, the "_Api" part of the requested URL does not match the "_API" part of the base href.

This is very inconvenient bug. You can work around it by modifying your base href to match the URL that was used to navigate to your app.

In the wwwroot/index.html file place the following script before blazor webassembly include:

```html
<script>
    let baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
    let baseHref = baseTag.getAttribute('href');
    let href = window.location.pathname.substr(0, baseHref.length)
    if (!href.endsWith('/')) href += '/';
    baseTag.setAttribute('href', href);
</script>
```

Comment: Yep the reason was indeed that the url in WebAssembly is case sensitive as you said, your script replaces the base href tag according to current browsing url, yet I preferred to change the base url to match "SincroADR_Api". Thanks.

Comment: Today I changed my mind, your script is very useful if you host multiple version of the webassembly application in different virtual directories. Thanks.

Comment: @fededim Be aware that this script relies on the length of the base path being the same in the requested URL and the initial <base> href. So if your virtual directory has different length, this will not work.

If all your virtual directories have the same "depth", you can search the actual pathname for n-th forward slash instead.

Comment: I changed  let href = window.location.pathname, e.g. removed substr, for now Blazor apps are hosted on first level virtual directories, e.g. http://server/virtualdir

Answer (score 0):

If the Blazor Web Assembly app works while debugging but fails to load after deploying to IIS, then follow below steps

I faced this issue after deploying .Net Core 6.0 Blazor Web Assembly application to IIS

1. Open the Index file
2. Change the base href to your application virtual directory

[image]

3. Clear the Cache
4. Now browse your application
5. It should run as below

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).