# Unable to get a Blazor Webassembly app to publish as a sub-application of my domain

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor Webassembly hosted application. I want to run this application as a sub-app of my site, but at a specific path where I have other sub-apps. Example: site.com/folder/app. I have tried just about every combination that I can think of, using existing Microsoft documentation on deploying multiple Blazor webassembly apps, deploying Blazor webassembly in general, etc.

I can get the application to launch on localhost (via IIS Express). I can even get the index.html page to load on the server, but the client application will not run. All of my resources return 404 errors.

I have tried adding `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>` to my client.csproj (as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/multiple-hosted-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=route-subpath)) in a couple of different formats: `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>app</StaticWebAssetBasePath>` and `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>folder/app</StaticWebAssetBasePath>`. Not only does that not work, but it breaks my ability to launch via localhost (even when I set a condition to the property).

I have tried setting up different mappings (`app.MapWhen(...)`) so that I could route the middleware pipeline to different locations based on whether I was running on localhost or the server. Again, nothing.

I am targeting .Net 7 with the latest and greatest installed on my IIS server.

**EDIT**
My wasm application is being deployed to a virtual directory in my site.

Comment: Is this case similar to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144275/getting-404-notfound-for-blazor-webassembly-js-framework-files-not-found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging on another error message that I was seeing, I found the answer in a completely unrelated question.

As @andris notes in their answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64478727/4454913), Blazor webassembly treats the base path as case sensitive. This is confirmed in Github ticket [#6818](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6818) in the dotnet/aspnetcore repository. Because of the case sensitivity (which I was unaware of), it was causing me to have the deployment errors I described above...Blazor couldn't find the files because it didn't know where to look. Finally, because I was publishing to a virtual directory, I didn't end up needing to  do any configuring of the middleware pipeline to tell the application where to find the static files. I could simply deploy my application, with stock configuration.

Answer (score 0):

for your information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path

Usually set  tag in index.html,the base tag must precede all introduced CSS and JS.
Alternatively, you can use JS to set the base path.
Here is my approach:

```js
......
<title>BLZUI</title>
<base />
<script async>
(async () => {
  let flag = true;
  let path = window.location.href;
  while (flag) {
    var response = await fetch(
      `${path.replace(RegExp("\\/+$", "g"), "")}/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js`
    );
    if (response.status != 200) {
      path = path.slice(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    } else {
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  var base = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
  base.setAttribute("href", path.replace(window.location.origin, ""));
})();
</script>
......
```